# Creating a reactive R item that will change which variable from a dataset is used based on a selection from a text box in the UI

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am just starting out with R shiny and have been able to create some nice reactive text boxes to change displays etc.

I am now looking to do a similar thing but to read in a certain variable form my dataset depending on which variable is typed in my text box.

The standard R code to create the `xvar` object containing the variable `AGE` from my input dataset `pauldata` works fine. I can then go onto to use this variable in my plot no worries.

```
xvar <- pauldata$AGE
```

However, now I wanted to change what variable is read in from my `pauldata` dataset based on what is entered in my text box object called `xv` (in this case I would enter `AGE` in the text box)

I tried this:

```
xvar2 <- reactive({pauldata$input$xv})
```

Logically, I felt that this would work and then I can later use `xvar2` (or maybe `x2var()`) in my plot statement where `xvar` was previously.

If I try this then I get errors relating to the length of y an x not being equal in my plot, hence I do not think that `xvar2` has been assigned how I intend it to be.

I assume it is possible to read in datasets and then make variable selection from that dataset be reactive to entries in your UI?

Comment: Please try provide a min reprex to allow us to help you better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values from a `selectInput` are returned as a character vector, so you need to use the `[[` operator instead of the `$`. Also input values are also already reactive so no need to wrap in `reactive()`

I think this is what you were trying to accomplish:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  h1("Everyone's 2nd Favorite Data Set"),
  selectInput("xv", "Select Variable", choices = names(iris[-5])),
  plotOutput("plot")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(iris[[input$xv]], xlab = input$xv, main = "")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: How about when you try to use a similar approach for creating a new dataset which filters an existing dataset, the variable i am using is the one that i want to filter all cases where it = Y. I figured this approach would work (similar to what you suggested), but it did not:  This works OK by selecting where varx=Y pauldata2 <- pauldata[pauldata$varx %in% "Y",] but this next version which is supposed to replace varx with whatever is in the sel1 box doesnt
    pauldata2 <- reactive({pauldata[pauldata[[input$sel1]] %in% "Y",]})

Comment: What I think you're asking is how to have the user select a column on which to filter (`input$sel1`) and then capture a subset of rows based on values in this column, but I'm having a little trouble following along. 

If this answers your initial question, can you mark this as answered and create a new question with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Just post a link here and I'll be happy to try to help (though by adding a new question you will likely attract others as well)